# using a variable to identify file in 'print -dpdf file_name'

Tags: octave

I am trying to use a formatted string to identify the file location when using 'print -dpdf file_name' to write a plot (or figure) to a file.

I've tried:

```
    k=1;
    file_name = sprintf("\'/home/user/directory to use/file%3.3i.pdf\'",k);
    print -dpdf file_name;
```

but that only gets me a figure written to ~/file_name.pdf which is not what I want. I've tried several other approaches but I cannot find an approach that causes the the third term (file_name, in this example) to be evaluated. I have not found any other printing function that will allow me to perform a formatted write (the '-dpdf' option) of a plot (or figure) to a file.

I need the single quotes because the path name to the location where I want to write the file contains spaces. (I'm working on a Linux box running Fedora 24 updated daily.)

If I compute the file name using the line above, then cut and paste it into the print statement, everything works exactly as I wish it to. I've tried using

```
    k=1;
    file_name = sprintf("\'/home/user/directory to use/file%3.3i.pdf\'",k);    
    print ("-dpdf", '/home/user/directory to use/file001.pdf');
```

But simply switching to a different form of print statement doesn't solve the problem,although now I get an error message:

```
    GPL Ghostscript 9.16: **** Could not open the file '/home/user/directory to use/file001.pdf' .
    **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
    warning: broken pipe
```

Comment: Andy's answer corrected this but he forgot to point it out explicitly, so just pointing out that surrounding your string with single quotes as well as double quotes is unnecessary (worse, it will cause an error, because octave will look for a filename with literal single quotes in the name).

Comment: also, since you mentioned you couldn't find alternatives, just pointing out there's also `saveas(gcf, file_name)`

Comment: I need the single quotation marks because the path name has spaces in it.

Comment: The saves as function does work either:

        saveas(1, file_name, "pdf");
gives the same error as using Andy's print command structure.@TasosPapastylianou @Andy

Comment: when you create a string with double quotes, any single quotes inside it become literal characters. You do NOT need to put single quotes in the string. The string you create will interpret spaces literally and thus parse correctly as a filename with spaces. If you add single quotes, it's like passing a different filename, one that contains literal quotes as part of its name. E.g. if your file was `My 'educational' movies folder/anatomy.avi` then you would create that in matlab as s = sprintf("My 'educational' movies folder/anatomy.avi"). The single quotes would not disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe:

```
>> k=1;
>> file_name = sprintf ('/home/tasos/Desktop/a folder with spaces in it/this is file number %3.3i.pdf', k)
 file_name = /home/tasos/Desktop/a folder with spaces in it/this is file number 001.pdf
>> plot (1 : 10);
>> print (gcf, file_name, '-dpdf')
```

[image]

Tadaaa!

So yeah, no single quotes needed. The reason single quotes work when you're "typing it by hand" is because you're literally creating the string on the spot with the single quotes.

Having said that, it's generally a good idea when generating absolute paths to use the `fullfile` command instead. Have a look at it.

Comment: whats the difference to my answer and why haven't you accepted Tasos answer if it solves your issue?

Comment: Tasos stayed with me to help me overcome my wrong-headed assumptions@Andy

Comment: Hahah, I appreciate the sentiment @LeeDuke , but for future reference, mark answers as accepted if they represent the most appropriate answer to your specific question, rather than a nice guy :p ; the point being, future users with the same question who bump into this page will take that as the answer. Also, Andy's answer pointed out the other problem with your code, namely that `print filename -dpdf` is identical to `print("filename","-dpdf")` which is not the same as `print(filename, "-dpdf")`. I would have at least upvoted his answer as it provided valuable information to your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you use `foo a b` this is the same as `foo ("a", "b")`. In your case you called `print ("-dpdf", "file_name")`

```
k = 1;
file_name = sprintf ("/home/user/directory to use/file%3.3i.pdf", k);
print ("-dpdf", file_name);
```

Comment: now now Andy, copy/pasting isn't an excuse, you need to be consistent with the octave style guide :p

Comment: Let me be more explicit:
If I determine the file_name variable first then move the string by cutting and pasting manually, the print works exactly as I wish it to. Thus, if I use,
    k=1;

Answer (score 0):

Tasos Papastylianou @TasosPapastylianou provided great help. My problem is now solved.

Comment: Pleasure. note that I only saw this by accident, one only gets notified if they're tagged in a comments discussion they participated. Also, the proper way to accept a particular answer is to mark it as accepted, and the proper way to demonstrate *any* answer contributes something useful is by upvoting it (people generally do both). This also awards "reputation" points to users as an added incentive to help out :p

Comment: so, please consider removing this 'answer' and marking one of the above (the one you think is the most representative answer to your question) as accepted instead :)   This also flags the question green (as having been answered) when people google for it etc.